# Is it possible to specify "main" file when launching node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I am wondering if there is a way to specify the index file that is opened up when node-webkit is launched. i.e., I am trying to override the `"main"` key in the manifest file.

Here is a basic example of a setup and what I want to do:

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "nw-demo",
  ...
}
```

The package looks something like this:

```
app.nw
| -- package.json
` -- index.html
` -- anotherIndex.html
...
```

Desired command:

```
nw app.nw --main="anotherIndex.html"
```

I am aware of the `--url="FILE.html"` command line switch specified [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Command-line-switches), but when I pass this param node-webkit fails to open at all.

Answer (score 2):

Node Webkit can support opening the file, as you want it to. This code is not bullet-proof, but it should get you started.

Follow these steps:

1. Place the following JavaScript in the head of your default index.html page:

   ```
   window.gui = require('nw.gui');

   checkFile = function()
   {
       var arg = window.gui.App.argv[1];
       if (arg)
       {

           window.location = arg;

       }
   }
   ```
2. Now add this to the body tag : `onLoad="checkFile();"`
3. You should now be able to call Node WebKit from the command line as follows:

nw app.nw startwiththisfile.html

If startwiththisfile.html is in your app.nw package, it should launch.

Comment: In this example, is `credits.html` part of the `app.nw` package? This isn't working for me. Providing any path (absolute or not) with the switch doesn't open the app for me.

Comment: The credits.html file is a physical file located in the same folder as the nw.exe application.  Are you sure you are giving the full, physical path to the file?

Comment: Oh, wait, you want to launch an alternative file IN the app.nw package?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do. Moreover, I am certain I am providing the correct full physical path. However I am testing this on Mac, not Windows.

Comment: Chris, the OS doesn't matter, that file doesn't exists before the app has extracted it, let me dig a little bit, I have an idea.

Comment: I've made some changes, it took a while to get it, JavaScript is a language I'm still learning, I just finished CodeCademy a few weeks ago :)

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! Once I get a chance to try it out I'll let you know.

Comment: Please do, I tested it on my Windows and Linux boxes, you might need to change the [0] of the index depending on how the Mac passes arguments.

Comment: `if(process.platform == "darwin") index=0; else index=1;` should make it compatible across windows and mac.